# Choosing different page templates for different pages with is_home()

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress 3.9.1 website with the Twenty Fourteen theme.
Normally the theme lets me choose from 3 different templates it has for every page which are Default - Full-Width - Contributor Page.

For the home page I am using **full-width template** which also calls another template part called **content-page.php**

I created another file called **content-pagehome.php** and copied everything from **content-page.php** and added some content inside like this;

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> class="homepage-content-styles">
<?php
    // Page thumbnail and title.
    twentyfourteen_post_thumbnail();
    the_title( '<header class="entry-header"><h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1></header><!-- .entry-header -->' );
?>

<div class="entry-content">
    <?php
        the_content();
        wp_link_pages( array(
            'before'      => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyfourteen' ) . '</span>',
            'after'       => '</div>',
            'link_before' => '<span>',
            'link_after'  => '</span>',
        ) );

        edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyfourteen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' );
    ?>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->

<!-- This is the part I've added -->

<div style="margin-top:7%;">
<h5 style="margin-left:5%;"><a title="Buscas hotel en Costa Rica?" href="http://veranta.com/country/costa-rica-hotels/buscas-hotel-en-costa-rica/">Hoteles en Costa Rica</a></h5>
<h5 style="margin-left:5%;"><a title="Buscas hotel en Panama?" href="http://veranta.com/country/ofertas-y-hoteles-en-panama/buscas-hotel-en-panama/">Hoteles en Panama</a></h5>
<h5 style="margin-left:5%;"><a title="Buscas hotel en Nicaragua?" href="http://veranta.com/country/book-nicaragua-hotels/buscas-hotel-en-nicaragua/">Hoteles en Nicaragua</a></h5>
<h3 style="text-align: center; margin-left:4%; margin-top:10%;"><strong>Veranta trabaja con los mejores proveedores de reservaciones de la región <br class="none" /> y directamente con hoteles, B&amp;B, y condominios para conseguir <br class="none" /> la mejor oferta de hoteles de Centroamérica.<br class="none" /> Compare cientos de precios en solo lugar<br class="none" /> y ahorre en sus reservaciones de hotel.</strong></h3></div>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

And then in the **full-width.php** I've changed the statement where it calls content-page.php to an if else statement;

```
get_header(); ?>

<div id="main-content" class="main-content">

<?php
if ( is_front_page() && twentyfourteen_has_featured_posts() ) {
    // Include the featured content template.
    get_template_part( 'featured-content' );
}
?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
        <?php
            // Start the Loop.
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            //if it is home get template part content-page-home.php else get content-page.php
            if ( is_home() ) {
                // Include the page content template.
                get_template_part( 'content', 'pagehome' );
            } else {
                get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
            }
                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                    comments_template();
                }
            endwhile;
        ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- #main-content -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

The website is online here veranta.com
I can add more information if needed!

Still it is not calling the **content-pagehome.php**. I have cleared my caches etc. and checking which templates it uses from admin panel thanks to *what the file* plugin.

Can you see anything wrong here? Any help would be really useful. Thanks for your time!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the different ways to detect home page in wordpress?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920736/what-are-the-different-ways-to-detect-home-page-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, still want to keep this question as a reference for others.

There are two different boolean functions which are `is_home()` and `is_front_page()`.

`is_front_page()` is the right option in my case because I have a static page displaying on the Front Page and in the function reference it says:

It returns TRUE when the main blog page is being displayed and the Settings->Reading->Front page displays is set to **"Your latest posts"**, or when is set to **"A static page"** and the "Front Page" value is the current Page being displayed.

If I had a **Blog Post Index** ("Your Latest Posts" option at Customize)
I would need to use `is_home()` as it says in the reference:

`is_home()` checks if the blog posts index page is being displayed as the Front Page.

I still can't close this question cause I can't accept my answer in two days. If you think that this has to be closed, please vote for it.

Thanks.